# CakePHP Fields not updating on Edit Page

Tags: php, cakephp

I have been working with cakephp and have been able to create a few simple models and relationships. I have been specifically trying to implement the hasMany association. My issue comes from trying to update child items.

For the purposes of my example, I'll assume that I have a 'Parent' and a 'Child' model class. I am able to create to the view and add pages without any issues. However, I am not having the  same success with the edit page. On the edit page, I am able to display both the Parent fields as well as the Child fields. However, when I go to save the form, instead of updating the child items, it just adds those rows in addition to the existing ones. I am not sure why this is occurring. Am I missing a parameter somewhere?

This is my code for the Edit page

```
echo $this->Form->create('Parent', array('action' => 'edit'));
echo $this->Form->input('title');
echo $this->Form->input('body', array('rows' => '3'));
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));

$x = 0;
foreach($this->request->data['Child'] as $child){
    print $this->Form->input("Child.$x.name");
    $x++;
}
```

And this is the edit function in my ParentController

```
   public function edit($id = null) {
    $this->Parent->id = $id;
    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        $this->request->data = $this->Parent->read();
        } else {
            if ($this->Parent->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been updated.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to update');
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at your source code to make sure that the form action is /controller/edit/id and not just /controller/edit ? Since you are assuming a default value of id to be null, that could be expected to happen.

Comment: Before anyone jumps down my throat pointing out that he has $this->data['Parent']['id'] as a hidden field, this WILL BE OVERRIDDEN by setting $this->Parent->id to $id. If $id is null, it will insert new rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting this before the `saveAll`:

I know that when saving multiple related data, you need to validate which ID will be used.

`unset($this->Parent->Child->validate['parent_id']);`

Resources: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data